# Is it possible to use opengl or directx with visual basic with only visual studio installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, opengl, directx

I was wondering if it is possible to use opengl or directx with only visual studio installed on the system. I can not install anything else since it is a school computer I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

With OpenGL it's possible. You will only need to download the OpenGL .dll's and link them to your project. There are some tutorials for that online.

You can find some tutorials on NeHe. http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lessons_01__05/22004/

EDIT:
I just read you want to use VB. It's another story then. While this edit it's not an answer on your question, I suggest using C++.
All I know is a wrapper for C#, called CsGL. http://csgl.sourceforge.net/faq.html#vsnet
Also Tao Framework: http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~crawfis/cse581/Homework/TaoSetup.html

Or have a look at: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Language_bindings , at the section VB.

Comment: It has to be vb because it is supposed to be extra credit for a class, and my professor said that I couldn't download anything extra because he wants to use what I make as an example for future classes and they cant install anything on the lab machines. I have done a good amount of searching and have pretty much figured out that with his stipulation of not being able to download anything, that it is impossible. I just wanted to get some feedback before I went back and talked to him to make sure I was right.

Comment: Well, OpenGL has better portability and with the last link I provided, you can give it a try.